# BackboneJS - Add class to clicked element after rendering

Tags: jquery, json, backbone.js

Can I add a class to the parent `<li>`-element after the relevant `<a href>` has been clicked and the view has been rendered? Can I use the `afterRender`-function

I have a view like this:

```
function (App, Backbone) {

    var Alphabet = App.module();
    var LetterView = Backbone.View.extend({
        template: 'alphabetlist',
        tagName: 'li',
        serialize: function() {
            return this.model.toJSON();
        }

    });

    Alphabet.View = Backbone.View.extend({
        tagName: 'ol',
        className: 'alist',
        initialize: function() {
            this.listenTo(this.collection, 'all', this.render);
            this.listenTo(this.collection, 'sync', this.onSync);

            this.collection.fetch();        
        }, 

        beforeRender: function() {
            var self = this;

            this.collection.each(function(item) {
                self.insertView(new LetterView({model: item}))
            })
        }
    });
    Alphabet.AlphabetCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
        url: 'js/json/AlphabetCollection.json'
    });

    return Alphabet;
}
```

My JSON file looks like:

```
[
{
    "name":"0-9",
    "id":"1",
    "url":"special"
},
{
    "name":"A",
    "id":"2",
    "url":"a"
},
{
    "name":"B",
    "id":"3",
    "url":"b"
},
   ...etc.

]
```

and the HTML-template:

```
<a href="#artists/{{url}}">{{name}}</a>
```

I want to achieve that the parent `<li>`-element becomes some kind of "active" class so it indicates, which letter has been clicked and which list of groups which names starts with the rleevant letter is displayed.

can someone help me out?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1):

It's actually quite simple, assuming the anchor is inside of the `LetterView` `alphabetlist` template:

```
var LetterView = Backbone.View.extend({
    template: 'alphabetlist',
    tagName: 'li',
    serialize: function() {
        return this.model.toJSON();
    },
    events: {
      'click a': 'onClick'
    },
    onClick: function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      this.$el.siblings('.is-active').removeClass('is-active');
      this.$el.addClass('is-active');
    }
});
```

Comment: Actually that is what I also expected to work, but since a new layout/page gets rendered after I clicked (I use layoutmanager), this solution has no effect at all!

Comment: Ah. If the view is getting re-rendered after the anchor is clicked then you will need to store the "picked" state of the model so you can restore the `active` flag upon re-render. [Backbone.picky](https://github.com/derickbailey/backbone.picky) can help with this.